# Component not updating after useEffect call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete an Item from my database using a Modal and then show the list of item remaining.

Everything works, my item is deleted correctly, but my component update only when I navigate to it, it's not updating after my modal is closed.

I want my component to refresh after my modal is closed.

Here is my code:
My modal:

```
<Modal visible={modalOpen} transparent={true} animationType='fade'>
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteMachineFunction()}>
         <Text style={styles.delete}>Delete</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

my deleteMachineFunction() which is called after pressing 'Delete'

```
    const deleteMachineFunction = () => {
        dispatch(deletemachine(machineId))

        firebase.firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc('WDaEyHg9wMhqFjqA1zzeYaD6sts1')
        .update({
            userMachineList: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(machineId)
        })
        //close modalle modal
        setModalOpen(false)
    }
```

So above, my modal useState (`modalOpen`, `setModalOpen`) is updating true to false.

Here is my useEffect hook:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            firebase.firestore()
            .collection("users")
            // .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .doc('WDaEyHg9wMhqFjqA1zzeYaD6sts1')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if(snapshot.exists){
                   setCloudUserMachineList(snapshot.data().userMachineList)
                } else {
                    console.log('not working')
                }
            })
        });
    
        // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
        return unsubscribe;

      }, [navigation, modalOpen]);
```

I was thinking by putting `modalOpen` in the useEffect array, my Component will update automatically after modalOpen turn to false but it's not working.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you put modal in a component that is rendered, because if its not rendered how will the useEffect take effect (eg: App.js is always rendered, Home.js is rendered when you navigate to home page....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you call `get()`, you're only getting the data once. If the data is updated after that, your `setCloudUserMachineList` won't be updated.

If you want to [*listen* for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to the data, use `onSnapshot` instead of `get()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc('WDaEyHg9wMhqFjqA1zzeYaD6sts1')
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => { // 
        if(snapshot.exists){
           setCloudUserMachineList(snapshot.data().userMachineList)
        } else {
            console.log('not working')
        }
    })
}, [modalOpen])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update data only on modal close and open, then your `useEffect()` function can be written like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    // .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .doc('WDaEyHg9wMhqFjqA1zzeYaD6sts1')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        if(snapshot.exists){
           setCloudUserMachineList(snapshot.data().userMachineList)
        } else {
            console.log('not working')
        }
    })
}, [modalOpen])
```

it will get fresh data from firebase every time the modal is opened or closed and I don't understand why you added this functionality as a focus listener to navigation.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working, I have a navigation listenner because the user can edit items in other screens, so everytime he comes back to the home screen it's automatically refreshed (this part works).